# nginx isn't loading (include additional-hosts/*.conf;) wont change directory? centos7

Tags: wordpress, nginx, varnish, php, centos7

I'm fairly new to Linux and I'm having a little trouble setting up my web server... I am using LEMP with Varnish and phpMyAdmin. The server is running and I can access phpMyAdmin over https etc. Now I'm trying to setup Wordpress on another directory using the include /directory/*.conf; however it doesn't seem to load the file(s). It will only load the default directory set in nginx.conf

Here's my nginx.conf,

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

include       /etc/nginx/v-hosts/*.conf;

index   index.php index.html index.htm;

server {
    listen  127.0.0.1:8080;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location / {
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index  index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
location ~* ^/stolenmx.com/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ { root /srv/www/;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index  index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
}


server {
listen       443;
client_max_body_size 80M;    

ssl                  on;
ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

ssl_session_timeout  5m;

ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

location / {
root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
index  index.html index.htm;
}
location ~* ^/phpMyAdmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ { root /usr/share/;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index  index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
}
}
```

And here's my file i'm trying to load for wordpress,

```
server {
server_name stolenmx.com;
listen 8080;
access_log /var/log/nginx/stolenmx.com-access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/stolenmx.com-error.log;
root /srv/www/stolenmx.com;

location / {
    index index.php;
}

# Disable favicon.ico logging
location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

# Allow robots and disable logging
location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

# Enable permalink structures
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite . /index.php last;
}

# Handle php requests
location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/stolenmx.com$fastcgi_script_name;
}

# Disable static content logging and set cache time to max
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
}

# Deny access to htaccess and htpasswd files
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
}
}
```

I have included this files directory in nginx.conf "include       /etc/nginx/v-hosts/*.conf;" but for some reason it's not loading it and won't point the server_name to /srv/www/ ?

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why it won't load additional server.conf ?

I can drag the wordpress install into /usr/share/nginx/html and it works but then I can't have any more than one server. I think it's something to do with my nginx.conf but not sure what to change / add?

Regards Crafty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before changes can affect you need to restart/reload your nginx, in CentOS it's done by running:

```
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

(If you are not root use sudo)

You are requiring that all your included files will be suffixed with '.conf', please make sure your file has this extension. Last thing, you configured your Wordpress server to listen on 8080, did you checked on this port?

Comment: Hi, I have restarted nginx many times using 'systemctl restart nginx' but still no change, the file is 100% .conf as it's a server config file and has to be this extension. Lastly I'm using varnish cache which runs and displays the cache files on port 80 but listens for the live site on 8080 so it can cache it.